# SSH remote not working on Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, server, remote-server, macos-catalina

Remote ssh on visual studio was working okay. But I just installed the Docker extension. After that, VS tries to load everything from the `.profile` file on my remote and it does not work. I uninstalled the Docker extension. I think deleting/editing some files written by VS on remote machine should help(inside `.vscode-server` folder). Could you please help me in figuring this out?

This is what I see in the log output file.

```
6e1dff78f10: running
Acquiring lock on /home/username/.vscode-server/bin/3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316/vscode-remote-lock.username.3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316
Installation already in progress...
If you continue to see this message, you can try toggling the remote.SSH.useFlock setting
76e1dff78f10: start
exitCode==24==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==centos==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/609516==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
76e1dff78f10: end
```

Comment: I found out the solution. I had to kill VS code server on host. I hope this will be helpful to someone else...

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the VS Code command : `Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host...`

1. Open the command palette (`Ctrl` + `Maj` + `P` or `View`->`Command Palette...`)
2. `Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host...`
3. Choose your problematic host
4. Restart VS Code
5. Try again

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Worked for me, how to explain this behaviour ? With other servers, SSH connection was still okay